# Strange rectangles appearing when writing text in pygame

Tags: python, text, pygame, iteration

I'm new to pygame and python in general, so I suppose there's a possibility for major errors here.

I'm trying to make text appear in a dialog box. I've worked out the system and the text appears correctly, but when the text loads, a vertical rectangle symbol appears at the end of the text.

It seems clear to me that this symbol represents the 'return' key.
Here's the text file I'm pulling from:

```
00*It’s your favorite game console.
01*-Player's House-
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mko5D.jpg) how the text appears in-game.

And here's my code to break down the text file into segments:

```
with open("textList.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        cutInfo = line.split("*")
        if dblock.textnum == cutInfo[0]:
            self.text = cutInfo[1]
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to get rid of the rectangle without simply cutting off the end of the string, and I also want to preserve the returns within the text file so it's more readable (And isn't condensed into a single line). However, if there's no workaround, I suppose I could make those changes.

Comment: Can you show full code?

Comment: I suspect it's a carriage return or line feed. Where did this text file come from? What editor created it? What operating system?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS Sierra, and I made the text file in the standard TextEdit application, with "rich text" turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for line in file:` retains the trailing newlines.

You can use `line.strip()` to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace.

```py
cutInfo = line.strip().split("*")
```

If you don't want to get rid of all whitespace,

- `.strip('\r\n')` gets rid of newline characters only.
- `.rstrip('\r\n')` gets rid of trailing newline characters only.